# Mixin not outputting @each function

Tags: sass

I am trying out @each which works fine without @mixin but when I make it flexible with @mixin it doesn't output anything. I cannot figure out what am I missing?

```
$buttons : (
    default : $color-primary,
    success : #63cc82,
    error   : #e4757e,
    warning : #fd7856,
    info    : #927bc1,
)
```

mixin

```
@mixin themes($map){
    @each $button, $color in $map {
        &--#{$button}{
            background:$color;
        }
    }
}
```

and I am calling it like

```
@include themes(buttons)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in your map as a variable like so:

```
@include themes($buttons)
```

Comment: No, you need to pass in the variable with the `$` prefix

Comment: Great, thanks, It was annoying that sass don't give out errors.